# ChromeDriver Reference

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to create a reference for ChromeDriver from a property in a method in a separate class.
I getting an error when I call the reference in program.cs.
I have attached a screen shot. Any help is really appreciated.

**This is the separate class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PersonCompanyAdvancedSearch
{  

    class PropertiesCollection

    {
      public static IWebdriver driver { get; set; }

   }
}
```

**This is the program.cs class.**
This is the error I'm getting on "new ChromeDriver(@"C:\ChromeDriver");"

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver' to 'PersonCompanyAdvancedSearch.IWebdriver'

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace PersonCompanyAdvancedSearch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PropertiesCollection.driver = new  ChromeDriver(@"C:\\ChromeDriver");
            PropertiesCollection.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.ie/");
            // omitted for brevity...
```

Comment: Clearly, the ChromeDriver class doesn't implement your IWebdriver interface.

Comment: Any plans to accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're trying to assign a new instance of the `ChromeDriver` class to an `PersonCompanyAdvancedSearch.IWebdriver`. The issue is that the `ChromeDriver` class actually inherits from the `OpenQA.Selenium.IWebdriver` interface.

Instead of using the `PropertiesCollection.driver` object use `OpenQA.Selenium.IWebdriver`.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;

class PropertiesCollection
{
    public static IWebdriver driver { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change PropertiesCollection to

```
class PropertiesCollection
{
  public static OpenQA.Selenium.IWebdriver driver { get; set; }
}
```